# Setting up server for android app

Tags: java, android

I have developed an android application and i need to set a server for sending and receiving data from clients. The server must also be able to run python script for data  mining.I want to code the server in java(for analysing the data obtained from mining and handling the client requests).

what will be the way to set the server for my purpose. I have read that servers can be set up in eclipse or installing apache in linux in a virtual machine. will anyone of them fit my need or is there any other better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends on your needs. If you want to run Python scripts from Java, I don't really see why you would code your server-side logic in Java and then use Python data-mining scripts (you might have some problems with execution of Python scripts through Java and server setup). I know that Python is much better in data-mining, so stick with it. Consider Python for server-side logic. In case you want to run data-mining script manually that doesn't really mater, so you can separate the languages.

In case you want to separate it into two languages, then you must install an application server for Java. There are plenty of options for that, even open-sourced (Wildfly, Glassfish, ...):
https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/04/top-10-open-source-java-and-javaee-application-servers/

You can set most of them in Eclipse for development, for production releases they can be installed either on Unix or Windows. The Apache option you mentioned is probably Apache Tomcat application server. You can read more about Java application server set-up in Eclipse:
http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Configuring_an_Application_Server_in_Eclipse.pdf

Comment: i doing this project with a friend. i am not quite familiar with python. so i decided to do the android and server portion and my friend will do the data mining portion.  i think ill just do the data mining portion manually rather than going through the hassle as it is for my semester project only.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the requirement, you can setup the server in many ways in any operating system like linux (fedora, ubuntu), windows, mac osx etc. There are many java web frameworks to follow to make your own server and provide API for mobile.
These are some java web frameworks:

1. [playframework](https://www.playframework.com/)
2. [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)
3. [Grails](http://guides.grails.org/#/index)

You can setup above and other frameworks and can setup in any enviorment. For initial, you can setup in your local system, then later you can upload into your remote server.
For setup, please see the respective framework's documentation.

It would be wise to choose json for communication between mobile and server. You can consume the API in android using default [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) or you can follow other opensource http connection library like [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit), [asynchttp](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) etc.

Comment: one question. would it be better to use a web service or just code my server to send data in jason format

Comment: The way you which send data to mobile in json format is the web service .i.e. API (You mentioned the same thing above). You can use http://www.mocky.io/ to mock the json for now.